# Crash in JourneyBuilder SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, android, salesforce-sdk-android

We are seeing this crash happen quite frequently in our production application. IS there anyway we can work around this because as of right now, it is our highest crash with our latest release. We are utilizing version 5.1.3 of the Android JourneyBuilder SDK. We haven't actually pushed any notifications yet.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String  android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>
> com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCTokenIntentService.onHandleIntent (Unknown Source)
>   android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage (IntentService.java:67)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no workaround for this issue, however it has been corrected in version 5.3.x of the SDK.

The current release, as of 20171214, is v5.3.2.

Comment: Bill, is there any reproduction steps to test this issue? Our QA team wanted to test the upgrade and ensure it actually fixed the issues

Comment: Sorry Trey K., we've never experienced this issue internally nor have we had any other reports of this issue.  This portion of the code was redesigned to better align with the rest of the architecture that changed in support of Android O's stricter requirements on background processing.  So, the fix unfortunately, is merely a happy coincidence -- not even sure how you'd get to onHandleIntent() with a null intent, but even Android's Javadoc says the field is @Nullable so that was a miss on our part for the version in question.